# Join on dataframes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, outer-join

I have two dataframes, containing up to top 3 counts for various string by a separate key(so each key can have up to 3 string counts):

df1:

```
key    var1    count
 0      abc      4
 0      lkj      2
 0      bcs      1
 1      zst      2
 1      stt      1
 1      sdf      1
 2      qwe      1
 3      dfg      8
 3      jkl      2
```

df2:

```
key    var1    count
 1      abc      4
 2      bcs      1
 3      zst      1
 4      stt      3
 4      sdf      1
 4      qwe      1
 5      dfg      5
 5      jkl      4
 6      oiu      3
 7      hkj      1
```

I need to do a full join by the key column, so that all counts would be combined by the key. The resulting dataset should look like this:

```
key    var1    count   key   var2     count
 0      abc      4
 0      lkj      2
 0      bcs      1
 1      zst      2     1      abc      4
 1      stt      1
 1      sdf      1
 2      qwe      1     2      bcs      1
 3      dfg      8
 3      jkl      2
                      4      stt      3
                      4      sdf      1
                      4      qwe      1
                      5      dfg      5
                      5      jkl      4
                      6      oiu      3
                      7      hkj      1
```

What would be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(),on=['key'], how='outer').set_index(['key'])
```